# Creating a Stopwatch progam for Python 3.3 only in IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment where I need to create a stopwatch, but only for IDLE. Here's what I have so far, I'm not sure how to convert the times to normal time.

```
import time
start = 0
def stopwatch():
    while True:
        command = input("Type: start, stop, reset, or quit: \n")
        if (command == "quit"):
            break
        elif (command == "start"):
            start = time.time()
            print(start)
            stopwatch2()
        elif (command == "stop"):
            stopwatch()
        elif (command == "reset'"):
              stopwatch()
        else :
            break

def stopwatch2():
    while True:
        command = input("Type: stop, reset, or quit: \n")
        if (command == "quit"):
            break
        elif (command == "stop"):
            total = time.time() - start
            print(total)
            stopwatch()
        elif (command == "reset'"):
              stopwatch()
        else:
            break

stopwatch()
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`datetime.timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
import datetime

print(datetime.timedelta(seconds=total))
```

For example:

```
In [10]: print datetime.timedelta(seconds=10000000)
115 days, 17:46:40
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this... Idle is really no different than coding in the interactive python interpreter which I do all the time (well, I use ipython).

Think of your stopwatch like an object. What functionality does it have? Things like start, stop, reset.

This may not be the most efficient way to solve the problem but here is what I would do.

```
>>> import time
>>> class StopwatchException:
    pass

>>> class IsRunningException(StopwatchException):
    pass

>>> class NotRunningException(StopwatchException):
    pass

>>> class Stopwatch():
    def __init__(self):
        self._times = []
        self._is_running = False
    def start(self):
        if self._is_running:
            raise IsRunningException
        self._is_running = True
        tracker = {
            'start': time.time(),
            'stop': None,
            }
        self._times.append(tracker)
    def stop(self):
        if not self._is_running:
            raise NotRunningException
        tracker = self._times[-1]
        # the dict is mutable, and tracker is a shallow copy
        tracker['stop'] = time.time()
        #print(self._times[-1])
        self._is_running = False
    def reset(self):
        if self._is_running:
            raise IsRunningException
        self._times = []
    def total(self):
        if self._is_running:
            raise IsRunningException
        total = 0.0
        for t in self._times:
            total += t['stop'] - t['start']
        return total

>>> s = Stopwatch()
>>> s.start()
>>> s.stop()
>>> s.total()
6.499619960784912
>>> s.reset()
>>> s.total()
0.0
```

To me, anytime you want to model a real world object or "thing", OOP makes the most sense. Heres a simple argument for each element of the program:

---

### Classes

- StopwatchException

  - Base exception class for the stopwatch class.
- IsRunningException

  - Raised if the stopwatch is running when it should be stopped.
- NotRunningException

  - Raised if the stopwatch is not running when it should be.
- Stopwatch

  - This represents the actual stopwatch.

### Stopwatch Class

- **init**

  > A basic stopwatch class really only needs to instance variables. A variable that stores each start/stop time (allows them to be computed later) and a variable that stores the "state" of the stopwatch (on/off or running/stopped).
- `start`

  1. First we need to make sure the stopwatch isn't already running.
  2. > Then we need to set it's state to running and store the time in `self._times`.
     >   I chose to use a local variable and store each time pair as a dictionary with the keys 'start' and 'stop'. I chose a dictionary because it is mutable. You could also have a list with index 0 being the start time and index 1 being the stop time. You cannot use a tuple for this since tuples are immutable.
     >   Also, the "temporary" variable is not necessary but I used it for readability.
- `stop`

  1. First we need to make sure the stopwatch is actually running.
  2. > Then we set the state as 'stopped' (using our boolean `self._is_running`) and store our stop time, similar to what we did with `start`. I think it doesn't matter whether you set the boolean at the beginning or the end, although I chose to set it at the beginning of the start function and the end of the stop function so that the times would not include the time needed to update a boolean variable (even though it's a trivial task, it could be much more complex in more complex programs).
- `reset`

  1. Make sure the stopwatch isn't running
  2. Set `self._times` to be an empty list.
- `total`

  1. Make sure the stopwatch isn't running.

     - Optional: You can stop the stopwatch here if it's running, but I prefer to raise an exception.
  2. Iterate through each list item in `self._times` and calculate the difference between stop and start.